# Why does the wc utility generate multiple lines with "total"?

Tags: shell, cygwin

I am using the wc utility in a shell script that I run from Cygwin, and I noticed that there is more than one line with "total" in its output.

The following function is used to count the number of lines in my source files:

```
count_curdir_src() {
    find . '(' -name '*.vb' -o -name '*.cs' ')' \
        -a '!' -iname '*.Designer.*' -a '!' -iname '.svn' -print0 | \
    xargs -0 wc -l
}
```

But its output for a certain directory looks like this:

```
$ find . '(' -name '*.vb' -o -name '*.cs' ')' -a '!' -iname '*.Designer.*' -a '!' -iname '.svn' -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l
     19 ./dirA/fileABC.cs
    640 ./dirA/subdir1/fileDEF.cs
    507 ./dirA/subdir1/fileGHI.cs
   2596 ./dirA/subdir1/fileJKL.cs
(...many others...)
     58 ./dirB/fileMNO.cs
     36 ./dirB/subdir1/filePQR.cs
 122200 total
  6022 ./dirB/subdir2/subsubdir/fileSTU.cs
    24 ./dirC/fileVWX.cs
(...)
    36 ./dirZ/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
    88 ./dirZ/fileYZ.cs
 25236 total
```

It looks like wc resets somewhere in the process. It cannot be caused by space characters in filenames or directory names, because I use the `-print0` option. And it only happens when I run it on my largest source tree.

So, is this a bug in wc, or in Cygwin? Or something else? The wc manpage says:

> Print newline, word, and byte counts
>   for each FILE, and a total line if
>          more than one FILE is specified.

It doesn't mention anything about multiple total lines (intermediate total counts or something), so who's to blame here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling wc multiple times - once for each "batch" of input arguments provided by xargs. You're getting one total per batch.

One alternative is to use a temporary file and the `--files0-from` option for `wc`:

```
$ find . '(' -name '*.vb' -o -name '*.cs' ')' -a '!' -iname '*.Designer.*' -a 
    '!' -iname   '.svn' -print0 > files

$ wc --files0-from files
```

Comment: two things: the reasons why xargs splits is batch can be seen in `xargs --show-limits` that shows the limits on your system. And you can avoid creating a file by piping and using `--files0-from=-` which reads from stdin

Comment: @Xavier: Maybe it's worth adding your own answer with that info.

Answer (score 5):

What's happening is that `xargs` is running `wc` multiple times.  `xargs` by default batches as many arguments as it thinks it can into each invocation of the command it's supposed to run, but if there are too many files it will run the command multiple times on subsets of the files.

There are a couple ways I see to fix this.  The first, which will break if you have too many files, is to skip `xargs` and use the shell.  This may not work well on Cygwin, but would look like this:

```
wc -l $(find . '(' -name '*.vb' -o -name '*.cs' ')' \
    -a '!' -iname '*.Designer.*' -a '!' -iname '.svn' )
```

and you also lose the print0 capabilities.

The other is to use an `awk` (or `perl`) script to process the output of your `find`/`xargs` combo, skip "total" lines, and sum up the total yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The command-line length is much more limited under cygwin than on a standard linux box, and `xargs` must split the input to respect those limits. You can check the limits with `xargs --show-limits`:

On cygwin:

```
$ xargs --show-limits < /dev/null
Your environment variables take up 4913 bytes
POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 25039
POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 20126
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 25039
```

On centos:

```
$ xargs --show-limits < /dev/null
Your environment variables take up 1816 bytes
POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 2617576
POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 2615760
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072
```

And to build on @JonSkeet's answer, you don't need to create an additional file, you can pipe your find results directly to wc, by passing `-` as argument to `--files0-from`:

```
find . -name '*.vb' -print0 | wc -l --files0-from=-
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid generation of multiple lines with "total" counts when feeding the `wc` utility with an enormous number of file paths as command line arguments, you can use an intermediate `xargs` to `cat` the contents of files to the stdin of `wc` (see [piping output of find to xargs wc gives unreasonable totals](https://superuser.com/q/531533)).

This is a workaround if your `wc` command does not have the `--files0-from` as mentioned by Xavier.

```
count_curdir_src() (
   export LC_ALL=C
   find . -name '*.vb' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1000 cat | wc -l 
)
```