# Can I get git stat to show me proper-lines-of-code?

Tags: git, diff, lines-of-code, cloc, code-statistics

The `git stat` subcommand (or `git log --stat` etc.) shows us the numbers of lines added and removed. This is obviously useful, but - sometimes you don't care about whitespace and comment additions and removals.

Is it possible to get git to compute its addition and removal statistics - for display purposes only naturally - other than as lines removed and added? e.g. perhaps run something like [cloc](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc) on the relevant files?

Comment: You cannot get *Git* to do this, but Git is a set of tools, and you can use its tools in combination with other tools that *do* do that sort of thing. You'll have to write a lot of software glue to make the tools work with each other.

Answer (score 0):

You would not be able to use native Git commands.

Only a third-party could have that kind of additional feature, like [`cloc`](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc) you mention.

It was [used here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31613207/6309), with two checkouts (one for each commits).