# How to see total lines of code in bitbucket dashboard?

Tags: bitbucket

There used to be a metric for total lines of code in my project on my bitbucket dashboard. I can't find it on the dashboard or any submenus anymore. Does anyone know where I can find this information in bitbucket?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to me that Bitbucket itself doesn't show this metric anymore.

There is however a "plugin" called [FishEye](https://support.atlassian.com/fisheye/), which gives detailed information about your code. They also seem to report the [LOC metric](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHEYE/About+the+Lines+of+Code+Metric).

There is a free trial period, but I believe the service costs money after a while.

Another option is to look into software that calculates this for you locally. For example: [CLOC](http://cloc.sourceforge.net). This of course requires you to fire up the program, instead of just reading it off the website.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using git and you're just wanting to know how many lines of code are in your git repository, you can do that with git.

[Count number of lines in a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822471/count-number-of-lines-in-a-git-repository)