# How to count the total number of line of code for JS, CSS, LESS, HTML files in a project?

Tags: javascript, css, gulp

I am looking for a way to count the total number of line of code for my front-end project.

At the moment I am using the [gulp-sloc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sloc)

```
gulp.task('sloc', function () {
    gulp.src(folders)
      .pipe(sloc());
});
```

But the CSS code is not included in the count.

- Do I miss some special configuration?
- Do you know any other similar
  plugin?

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you are using source control? In case that source control is Git, you can count the amount of code in the repo [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28858550/508355) – no extra tools required.

For a more detailed breakdown, [cloc](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc) may be helpful – have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29015302/508355) then. cloc doesn't depend on Git, or any other type of source control.

Comment: I am using SVN, do you know if there is any similar command on SVN?

Comment: I don't, unfortunately. But cloc doesn't depend on Git, so that might work for you (didn't make that clear enough in my answer, I have edited it now).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but rather prefer a solution based on gulp

Comment: Also looking at locmetrics's site, I cannot see reference to JS and CSS, I see mainly support for  C#, C++, Java, and SQL

Comment: @GibboK I think your last comment was meant for the other answer ;) cloc does support CSS and JS: https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc#Languages

Answer (score 1):

In windows OS there is also a gui tool http://www.locmetrics.com/ which you can use to count lines of code (LOC), blank lines of code (BLOC), comment lines of code (CLOC).

Comment: This tool can only be used for Programming languages like, C#, C++, Java, and SQL.