# Rough approximation of github bytes to loc

Tags: bash, git, github

I'm looking to see if there is a simple heuristic for getting an approximate lines of code from a repository based upon the byte size. For example, the following url gives us 219K bytes:

- https://api.github.com/repos/mojombo/grit/languages

```
{
    "Ruby": 219981
}
```

- And this answer suggests a great way for evaluating LOC: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29015302/651174

---

What do you think would be an average of bytes to LOC? I know files can be minified and it'll not be exact, but what might be a good/average ratio?

Answer (score 0):

Do a statistical analysis of sample code (Python, C++, Java, shell scripts, and others) from GitHub.  You're going to find an average with a huge standard deviation which will show that such an approach is probably not too meaningful.

Comment: ok and what were you able to find? It seems like if there's no content maybe you could just post this as a comment instead of an answer.